# Standing on a glass desk top

Tags: glass

I have to put pictures on a wall over my glass desk top.  It is 19" wide(front to back) 42 1/2 "long(left to right) and 3/16" thick and 40 1/2" between the inside edges of the supports left to right, and 11 3/4" front to back.  I weight 195 lbs.  Can I stand on this desk?

Answer (score 8):

I would not even suggest taking the chance that it could hold you up to stand on it. Think of the possible serious injury that could result if it were to break and give way when you were standing on it.

You would do well to just move the desk out away from the wall and use a step ladder or stool of some sort to get up to the area where you intend to hang the pictures.